# How to "debug" which process is slowing my Updates

Tags: visual-workflow, cpulimit

Is there a way I could see what is the Flow, or Apex trigger that seems to be looping a bunch of times in my salesforce instance?

Because of this issue, I haven't been able to do batch updates, because I always get the CPU Time limit exceeded.

I have work with debug logs a little bit, and not sure if that is the right way to go, but I find it kind of hard to read those.

Thank you!

Comment: Do you have any process builders that are performing field updates that are related to what you process in the batch? Also have you tried setting the scope chunk size to a small value instead of using default 200 for the batch?

Comment: I ask about process builders doing record updates because these cause a separate flow through DML processing each time...

Comment: Yes, but we do have a ton of those. Based on what you are saying, the issue is related mostly to us having a bunch of process that are doing field updates?

Comment: If you have lots of these this is probably causing your trigger to re-invoke loads of times and is probably a significant contributor to your problem. You should be able to use the developer console's [performance profiling view](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/engineering/2013/05/force-com-performance-profiling-using-the-developer-console.html) to help visualize what is happening.

Answer (score 3):

Open the Developer Console (Gear Icon > Developer Console in Salesforce), click on Debug > Change Log Levels... > Add/Change, then click Add, name it Profiling, set all fields/columns to NONE except for Profiling, which should be set to FINEST. Once selected, click Done, and Done again. Finally, click in Debug > Show My Current Logs Only to uncheck this feature. After this, you can run your transaction. You'll see a new log appear in the Logs tab in the Developer Console. Double-click to open it, and you'll see lines telling you which parts of execution took the most time. This should help you narrow down your problem.

Comment: Hi!
Tried this and got 3 logs.
"RollUp Batch Agent ec3..."
QueuableHandler"
"Dynamic_ASYNC"

Any idea which one I should check?

Comment: @Neto0291 It's not clear from the names. Do you see the Status column? Do any have a message other than "Success"? You'll want to try a bulk update to force the error, it should be obvious which is which when you get the error.

Comment: Dataloader is showing several hundred errors, but at the console level on my logs I can only see the ones for success. No error logs are being showed.